# How to store value of a textblock created only in code in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, augmented-reality

I'm trying to modify this AR motion sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Augmented-Reality-Motion-c23920b7

In the sample, the method "CurrentValueChanged" loops over each point in the application's list of points (front, back, right, left, top, bottom) and for each point, it projects a textblock containing one of these (front, back, right, left, top, bottom) associated with that point.

My problem is I'm trying to store the value of each individual textblock, that is (front, back, right, left, top, bottom) when it is projected, in a separate variable. But I'm not able to. Anyway I try, I simply get System.Windows.Control.TextBlock as the value in the variable or I get only the last two points in the list of points (top, bottom). I'm trying to store these points so that I can trigger a separate event.

I'll appreciate any help at all. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show the code where you save the `TextBlock.Text` to a variable.

Comment: I'm storing it like this: In the method 'CurrentValueChanged', there is a for loop that projects the textblocks. Within that for loop, I'm trying to assign whatever the value is in the textblock to a separate textblock like this: myTextBlock.Text = textBlocks[i].Text;